# Display second dropdown based on selection in first dropdown?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need that based on the choice made in "dropdown list type_w" show me the "dropdown list of lmg or marks".

I tried with `addEventListener ("")`, but it doesn't work for me.

I also used CSS with `"display: none" / "display: block"` and JavaScript with switch/case, but it doesn't works.

```
</select>
 <select id="type_w">
   <option value="null" selected> --- </option>
   <option value="lmg"> LMG </option>
   <option value="marks"> Marksman Rifle </option>
 </select>

 <select id="w_lmg" hidden>
   <option value="null" selected> --- </option>
   <option value="mg5"> MG5 </option>
 </select>

 <select id="w_marks" hidden>
   <option value="null" selected> --- </option>
   <option value="mk17"> MK17 Military </option>
 </select>
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you add the JS you tried as well?

Comment: your should use xmhttprequest object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just write a small jQuery code, I hope it'll help you out. Thanks

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#type_w').change(function() {
    $(".hide-submenu").hide();
    $("#w_" + this.value).show();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="type_w">
  <option value="null" selected> --- </option>
  <option value="lmg"> LMG </option>
  <option value="marks"> Marksman Rifle </option>
</select>

<select id="w_lmg" class="hide-submenu" hidden>
  <option value="null" selected> --- </option>
  <option value="mg5"> MG5 </option>
</select>

<select id="w_marks" class="hide-submenu" hidden>
  <option value="null" selected> --- </option>
  <option value="mk17"> MK17 Military </option>
</select>
```

Comment: While I am not in any way suggesting Hassan's code is incorrect, it most certainly isn't. I do feel that using jQuery (or any lib for that matter) for something this simple is overkill. A "sledgehammer to crack a nut" as the proverb goes.

Comment: Thank you @meDev for the comment, If my solution resolves your issue please mark as correct. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Without jQuery:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

 document.querySelector('#type_w').addEventListener("change", function (e) {

  document.querySelector('#w_lmg').classList.add('hidden');
  document.querySelector('#w_marks').classList.add('hidden');

  if(e.target.selectedIndex == 1) {
   document.querySelector('#w_lmg').classList.remove('hidden');
  }

  if(e.target.selectedIndex == 2) {
   document.querySelector('#w_marks').classList.remove('hidden');
  }

 });

});
```

```css
.hidden {
 display:none;
}
```

```html
<select id="type_w">
 <option value="null" selected> --- </option>
 <option value="lmg"> LMG </option>
 <option value="marks"> Marksman Rifle </option>
</select>

<select id="w_lmg" class="hidden">
 <option value="null" selected> --- </option>
 <option value="mg5"> MG5 </option>
</select>

<select id="w_marks" class="hidden">
 <option value="null" selected> --- </option>
 <option value="mk17"> MK17 Military </option>
</select>
```

Answer (score -1):

Ok, I'm going to provide the code you need to get this working, but I should say there are quite a few ways to do this. Without the full scope of context and the desired end result, it's difficult to say this is definitely the way to do it.

I won't ask you to change your HTML except for one key element, remove the "hidden" attribute. If you wish to hide/show HTML elements use CSS as your first point of call.

```
<script>

// run script once once the page has loaded
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {init()});

// this will apply the event handler to the primary select
function init() {
 // apply even handler to detect when primary select has changed
 document.querySelector("#type_w").addEventListener("change", function(ev){
  var selects = document.querySelectorAll("#w_lmg, #w_marks").forEach( 
   function(item){ 
    item.style.display = ("w_"+ev.currentTarget.value==item.id ? "inline" : "none") 
   }
  )
 });
}

</script>
```

As I say, you will need to remove the "hidden" attribute in your HTML to get the above to work. You could use .hidden but using CSS is (imo) the better solution here.

If you are wondering how to set the two secondary selects as hidden via CSS you could use this:

```
<style>
 #w_lmg, #w_marks { display: none }
</style>
```

or if you wish a JS solution, insert this code as the first line within the init() function:

```
// hide the two child <select> 
 document.querySelectorAll("#w_lmg, #w_marks").forEach(
   function(item) {
    item.style.display = "none";
   }
 );
```